# libgomp and MacOsx

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, openmp, linker-errors

I am using MacOS Mojave version 10.14.16 and I am trying to install http://www.rpl2.net/index.php (a programming language using Reverse Polish Notation as found on some HP calculators like the 48GX), supposed to work on MacOSX (they say "MacOS X (Xcode 3.1.4 + gfortran 4.5)").

So I have downloaded the latest stable release, cd to the folder, and wanted to run

```
./configure
make
make install
```

But the ./configure is failing due to "configure: error: Can not find libgomp !". There is no libgomp package I can install with brew (I already installed gcc which comes with gfortran and thought it would provide libgomp but apparently not).

Could someone help a poor applied mathematician trying to install a software on its macbook?

Thanks

EDIT

in my config.log I have this, maybe it will help:

```
configure:7433: checking for vim
configure:7449: found /usr/bin/vim
configure:7461: result: yes
configure:7507: checking for main in -lm
configure:7526: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -O2 -fno-strict-overflow    conftest.c -lm   >&5
configure:7526: $? = 0
configure:7535: result: yes
configure:7548: checking for pthread_mutex_init in -lc
configure:7573: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -O2 -fno-strict-overflow    conftest.c -lc  -lm  >&5
configure:7573: $? = 0
configure:7582: result: yes
configure:7687: checking for omp_get_num_procs in -lgomp
configure:7712: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -O2 -fno-strict-overflow    conftest.c -lgomp  -lc -lm  >&5
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:7712: $? = 1
```

Comment: Libgomp does normally come with gcc. Perhaps you just have to setup you dynamic linker paths? I do not know how that is done on a Mac, though.

Comment: Configure normally makes a log file with more information. What exactly is written there?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I do not even get why the configure wants to link with the library explicitly without using `-fopenmp`... I at least changed the tags so that they might attract the right experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say how you installed `GCC`. If you did it using **homebrew**, and

```
brew install gcc
```

you should be able to see:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10/libgomp.dylib
```

which would mean you need to compile with:

```
gcc ... -L /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/lib/gcc/10 -l gomp ...
```

Failing that, you can always search for `libgomp` with:

```
find /usr -name "lib*gomp*lib"
```

You can test which `gcc` you are using with:

```
type gcc
```

Comment: I installed it with brew. It is indeed located in the path you mentioned. However when I do gcc --version I get a "Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin" . So probably not the right version!

Comment: If you use **homebrew** it installs binaries (i.e. programs) into `/usr/local/bin` so you need to put that at the start of your PATH, then you will find **homebrew** GCC rather than the sawn-off Apple one.

Comment: Well I tried several things but nothing worked. In my path variable /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin. I have added aliases to my bash_profile alias gcc='gcc-10'; and in a new shell gcc --version gives the desired result "gcc-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0". However ./configure still fails: when adding which gcc at the top of the file, it says /usr/bin/gcc. So I don't how to get the script to pick the "right" gcc

Comment: Personally I would never alias `gcc`, I prefer to let my PATH do the talking. In any case, I am not familiar with that package. I would suggest you try running `./configure --help` or `./configure -h` and see if it tells you how to specify the compiler you prefer.

Comment: I followed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245891/installed-gcc-with-homebrew-now-how-to-use-that-gcc-instead-of-clang and the only thing that worked was to do ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gcc-10 /usr/local/bin/gcc before executing ./configure